# How to convert string to date in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format, data-conversion, string-to-datetime

I have string with format : `'20018-03-03 11:00:00'`, and i want to convert to `Date` but keeping this format. Is this possible? Because when I do something like this :

`Date.parse(string)`, I don't get this format, event when I use 
`SimpleDateFormat`. What I'm doing wrong ?

I tried this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.parse(entry.getValue(), formatter);
String formatDateTime = now.format(formatter);
// Date date = df.parse(sqlDate);
Date d = (Date) formatter.parse(formatDateTime);
```

Comment: 20018 - does that seem to be a valid year for you? Also avoid these old legacy Date classes, rather use LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime.

Comment: A `Date` object has no format, it's just a value so your question is not relevant. What you see when you do `System.out.print` on a date object is a string representation of the date in a default format. Whenever you need a date in a specific format you need to create a string from your `Date` object.

Comment: No, it is not possible. A `Date` cannot have a format. Also I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead stick with `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, the classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) that you are already using.

Answer (score 3):

- It might not be the case in other languages, but in Java the format used to parse a date is not stored in the date itself. Thus you have to reuse the same format when you want to print (format) a date.
- Old (`Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`) and new (`LocalDateTime`, etc.) API should not be mixed together. Stick to the new one unless you have legacy code to deal with.

  ```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  // Parse: String -> LocalDateTime
  LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-03 11:00:00", formatter);

  // Format: LocalDateTime -> String
  System.out.println(now.format(formatter));
  ```

Comment: In no other language either have I met a date kind of object that stored a format. It would also have been a nasty design. Objects belong in your model and business logic. Formats belong in your UI and in serialization, e.g. for transmission. They should not be mixed.

Comment: @OleV.V. Fully agree with you. But I have seen so many people expecting their date to be printed out with the same format they previously used to parse, I came to the conclusion that it was common behavior in some other poorly designed language.